# Settings API - adding setting fields dynamically?

Tags: admin, settings-api

Is there a way of adding [settings fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_settings_field) dynamically?

I have my own [Settings API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) options generator just like in Chip Bennet's [Oenology Theme](https://github.com/chipbennett/oenology), everything works perfect but I can't find a way to create dynamic fields.

Here's how I add option fields.

### 1. First I describe all fields:

```
 function my_options() {
    $options = array(
         array(
            'id' => '1',
            'title' => '1', 
            'type' => 'foo',
            'description' =>  'bar',
        ),
          array(
            'id' => '2',
            'title' => '2', 
            'type' => 'foo',
            'description' =>  'bar',
        ),
    );

   return $options;
 }
```

### 2. Then I generate fields:

```
foreach(my_options() as $field) {
    add_settings_field(
       $field['id'],
       $field['title'],
       "something",
       "else",
       "goes",
       "there"
    );
}
```

Then doing:

```
   <?php $opts = get_option('my_theme_settings_api'); 
   var_dump($opts); ?>
```

Returns all the fields.

But what If want to generate some of the fields "on the fly", eg. based on some other array, just like that:

```
function my_options() {

   // $myarray = some array of elements taken from different source, like json data from other website etc.
   $count = 0;
   foreach($myarray as $something) {
        $count++;
        $options[] = array(
            'id' => 'something'. $count,
            'title' => $something['title'],
            'type' => 'type',
            'desription' => $something['description'],
        );

   return $options;
 }
```

Then I'm getting the fields displayed using [do_settings_sections()](http://codex.wordpress.org/do_settings_sections) but I can't save them on admin pages and when I do `var_dump($opts);` just like in example above these options doesn't exist there.

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you would need a way to get those dynamic fields into the `my_options` function each time it's called. You could try creating your own filter to use:

```
function my_options() {
    $myarray = apply_filters( 'my_get_options_dynamically', array() );
    $count   = 0;

    foreach($myarray as $something) {
        $count++;
        $options[] = array(
            'id'         => 'something'. $count,
            'title'      => $something['title'],
            'type'       => 'type',
            'desription' => $something['description'],
        );

        return $options;
}

add_filter( 'my_get_options_dynamically', function() {
    // Some code to get the dynamic option array.
    return array( array(
        'title'       => 'Some option title',
        'description' => 'Some option description',
    ) );
} );
```

---